# stateflow collect not firing in fragment

Tags: android, android-mvvm, kotlin-stateflow, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have a below sample code where i am collecting uiState in fragment. Due to some reason uiState.collect not firing. Anything missing below code?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NewsFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentNewsBinding
private val viewModel by viewModels<NewsViewModel>()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentNewsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            viewModel.uiState.collect { uiState ->
                Log.d("TAG", "collect")
            }
        }
    }
    return binding.root
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class NewsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository,
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState(isLoading = false))
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

}

data class UiState(
  val isLoading = false,
  val list = emptyList()
)
```